# nidaqmx.Task: (OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found)

Tags: python, nidaqmx, daq-mx

The following code for data acquisition gives the below error

```
import nidaqmx
with nidaqmx.Task() as task:
    nidaqmx.Task.ai_channels.add_ai_voltage_chan("Dev1/ai0")
    task.read()
```

> OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found.

Do you know what is the reason and how to fix it?
Thanks, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Run this `pip install nidaqmx` command from cmd to install module.

Comment: Hi, nidaqmx is already pip installed. so this is not the problem...

Comment: Although nidaqmx is successfully installed, it throws the following warning:  "ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback"

Answer (score 0):

There are two different software packages you have to install:

- The Hardware driver (NI-DAQmx)
- The software driver package (Python package nidaqmx)

You are missing the Hardware driver. You can download it [here](https://www.ni.com/en-us/support/downloads/drivers/download.ni-daqmx.html#460239).